# TypeError: array[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I load a multidimensional array in php

```
for($y = 0; $y< $totaleventosaldia; $y++ ){

$arraynombres[$y] = array($arrayeventosaldia[$y][1]);

}
```

Pass the array to the javascript method

```
echo "<td><button id = '".$year."-".$month."-".$i."' type='button' class='btn-default' style=' border-style: solid; border-image: url(imagenes/rainbow.jpg) 30 round;' onclick='mostrarModal(".$idboton.",".$arraynombres.");' >".$i."</button></td>";
```

I keep getting array[i] is undefined i dont get it,

```
<script>
    function mostrarModal(idboton, eventos){


        var fechaboton = idboton;

        var array = [];     

        var acumuladordenombres;


        for(var i =0; i < eventos.length;i++){
            array[i] = eventos[i];
            acumuladordenombres = acumuladordenombres +' '+ array[i][0];
        }


        alert(acumuladordenombres);




    }
</script>
```

Help plz, have been couple hours with this.

Comment: You just cannot pass values from php to html like that.

For starters, `$arraynombres` is an array and cannot be echoed.

Comment: ohh thanks a lot, i will try passing a string and just chop it in the javascript then

Comment: That's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to put a PHP array directly to JavaScript.
Please try to json_encode it:

```
onclick='mostrarModal(".$idboton.",".json_encode($arraynombres).");'
```

Regarding your JavaScript I would suggest to directly use `eventos` instead of copying the elements to `array`:

```
for(var i =0; i < eventos.length;i++) {
    acumuladordenombres = acumuladordenombres +' '+ eventos[i][0];
}
```